# Android XMLSerializer cannot write all data into XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlserializer

Now, I am trying to write XML file in running uiautomation test by uiautomator.
I used XMLSerializer for write XML in android. It is OK. It write XML file while running test. One thing that it cannot write all data as shown below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<tests>
    <test>
         <no>1</no>
         <desc>Test One</desc>
    </test>
    <test>
         <no>2</no>
         <desc>Test Two</desc>
    </test>
    <tes
```

See, it cannot write all data. Here my code.

```
// Export XML file content.
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

serializer.setOutput(stringWriter);
serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

serializer.startTag(null, "tests");

for(Test test : testList){
    serializer.startTag(null, "test");

    serializer.startTag(null, "no");
    serializer.text(test.getNo());
    serializer.endTag(null, "no");

    serializer.startTag(null, "desc");
    serializer.text(test.getDesc());
    serializer.endTag(null, "desc");

    serializer.endTag(null, "test");
}

serializer.endTag(null, "tests");

// Write file.
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("test.xml");

fileWriter.write(stringWriter.toString());

fileWriter.close();
```

My testList has at least 15 test. So, it should write all tests. But it writes only 2. Why! I don't know.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: I would prefer to use Editable in this case. Like this: `Editable editable; editable.append("<Type> " + "Name"+ " </Type>" + "<Class>" +"Class Name"
        + "</Class> " );`. It's easier and does the same thing.

Comment: Yes Tushar, I remove Serializer and replace it by StringBuffer and use append method. Now, it is OK for me. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Glad to help. Want me to post it as an answer for others with the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) in this case.

**Example**:

```
 Editable editable;
....
....
....
 editable.append("<Type> " + "Name"+ " </Type>" + "<Class>" +"Class Name" + "</Class>");
```

It's easier and does the same thing. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that **"you are not ending document of serializer"** as follow:

```
serializer.endDocument();
```